# css animation make an item flow into the block

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I need the red square to resize from scale (100) to scale(1). But now, at the beginning of the animation its scale is 1 and only then starts increasing to 100. Can I make the red box block not to be shown at the beginning of the animation with its original size?

https://codepen.io/alex-filippovich/pen/ExeJEEP

```css
.container .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .box {
  -webkit-animation-name: hideit;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideit {
  0% {
    display: none;
    transform: scale(10)
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't be using) vendor prefixes for animation. See https://caniuse.com/css-animation.

Comment: @Nisha, answers go down there. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Do you mean you also want the box to have no width and height at the beginning, but it's to take its final width and height from the .box declaration, not the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the box to `opacity: 0;` and start the animation with `opacity: 1;`

```css
    .container .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 0 auto;  
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .container .box {
      -webkit-animation-name: hideit;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes hideit {
      0% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(10) }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      100% { opacity: 0; }  
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that the animation is taking 1s to start because the delay of 1s you used. If you remove that the animation starts with the block hidden.

But if you want to keep the delay, add the rule `display: none` to the `.container .box` selector and add `display: block` to the 50% and 100% steps of the animation.